# Pinging 8.8.8.8 via a windows 10 client going through windows server 2012 gives a request timedout error

Tags: windows-server-2012, virtual-machines, virtualbox

This is my setup in virtualbox.

A DHCP Scope of range 112.123.1.100 to 112.123.3.188, Length = 16, Router IP is 112.123.2.2 (this also is the IP of the server the DHCP is configured on).

After this I set my IP of the windows server 2012 manually to IP: 112.123.2.2. Subnet: 255.255.0.0 Gateway = 10.0.2.2 DNS1: 10.0.2.2 DNS2: 8.8.8.8

This virtualbox VM that the server is running on is on an internal NAT network type. To access the internet I configured a second adapter as NAT type as per this guide: https://www.nakivo.com/blog/virtualbox-network-setting-guide/

The server can Ping google.com so it has internet access.

The client:

I configure the VM as an internal NAT type. Now I set my IP address to the following:
IP: 112.123.3.95
Subnet: 255.255.0.0
Gateway: 112.123.2.2

DNS1: 112.123.2.2
DNS2: 8.8.8.8

After that in the VM in windows 10 Pro I join the servers domain (Workgroup).

When I ping the server from the client I get a response back in CMD but when I ping 8.8.8.8 I get a "Request timed-out" message in CMD.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Again, all of this is happening inside VM's off virtualBox.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that the client can indeed ping the server but the server can't ping the client for some reason, but the client was able to join the servers workgroup/domain. so I don't know what is happening there.

Comment: You should not use public IP addresses that do not belong to you. This can cause a wide variety of routing problems.

Comment: Yes I know this, But since it is an internal NAT network in VirtualBox I can assign whatever IP I want since the DHCP server of VirtualBox is between the internal Network and the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your client (112.123.3.95) is on the same subnet as the server (112.123.2.2) which is why local ping works.

However, the client default route points to the server for default route (to get to 8.8.8.8).

Since the server can ping 8.8.8.8, it would seem to me that your server does not have routing and remote access service enabled.

Comment: I indeed haven't added routing and remote access services if this is the only way to do what I want. So what you are saying is that I need to enable RRAS and after that pinging 8.8.8.8 from the client should work?

Comment: Just edited my original post, if you could take a look that would be splendid!

Comment: Definitely want to resolve the local ping issues first. Maybe try turning off firewalls on both server and client in case ICMP echo requests are being blocked by the client. I presume both your server and client VMs are using the same "NAT Network" (not just "NAT") so that they can talk to each other.

If that doesn't resolve it, try turning on RRAS since technically you are routing between two physical interfaces on the host (that contains the server and client VM).

Comment: And reboot the physical host each time you try something. I presume the physical host OS is Windows also... and  sometimes stuff just works after a reboot.

Comment: I managed to get it working fairly quickly after your RRAS suggestion. I am still going to look into the server not being able to ping the client. But now the client can Ping 8.8.8.8.